# Javascript 3 minute timer that repeats when complete and shows message at the end of each cycle

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdowntimer

I am making a speed dating timer that counts down from 3 minutes to 0, shows a "move on to next date" message, and then repeats.

I have been able to get the timer to count down to 0, and then restart after the interval I've set, but for some reason it will not display the message. My code is as follows

```
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
    // set time for the particular countdown
    var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        // if the time is 0 then end the counter
        if(time == 0) {
            el.innerHTML = "Move on to next date...";
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout(function() {
                countdown('clock', 3, 0);
            }, 2000);
        }
        var minutes = Math.floor( time / 60 );
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        var seconds = time % 60;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds; 
        var text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
        el.innerHTML = text;
        time--;
    }, 1000);
}
countdown('clock', 3, 0);
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this? What does `console.log(el)` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're falling through into the "set the time" part again after the 'set the text' part. It *is* updating the text, but then overwriting it with "00:00".

You should insert a return statement to stop it continuing, or wrap the clock part in an else block.

```
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
    // set time for the particular countdown
    var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        // if the time is 0 then end the counter
        if (time <= 0) {
            var text = "hello";
            el.innerHTML = text;
            setTimeout(function() {
                countdown('clock', 0, 5);
            }, 2000);
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        var minutes = Math.floor( time / 60 );
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        var seconds = time % 60;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds; 
        var text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
        el.innerHTML = text;
        time--;
    }, 1000);
}
countdown('clock', 0, 5);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTDJY/

Answer (score 3):

just try this code i have fixed it for you

```
<html>
<head>
    <Script>
    function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
// set time for the particular countdown
var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('element');
    // if the time is 0 then end the counter
    if(time == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.innerHTML = "Move on to next date...";
        }, 10);


        clearInterval(interval);

        setTimeout(function() {
            countdown('clock', 0, 5);
        }, 2000);
    }
    var minutes = Math.floor( time / 60 );
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    var seconds = time % 60;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds; 
    var text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    el.innerHTML = text;
    time--;
}, 1000);
}
countdown('clock', 0, 5);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="element">elelelelel</p>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. However, I did need to remove the single quotes from `var el = document.getElementById('element');` because element is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing

`innerHTML` to `innerText`

In my example the clock is just a div. If you are using textbox you need to use to use value.

Here's my complete solution.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
    // set time for the particular countdown
    var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        // if the time is 0 then end the counter
        if(time == 0) {
            el.innerText = "Move on to next date...";
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout(function() {
                countdown('clock', 3, 0);
            }, 10);
        }
        var minutes = Math.floor( time / 60 );
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        var seconds = time % 60;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds; 
        var text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
        el.innerText = text;
        time--;
    }, 10);
}
countdown('clock', 3, 0);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Clock</h1>
<div id="clock"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do it like this instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(UpdateTime(), 1000);
});

var interval = 3*60; // 3 minutes
function updateTime(){
   interval --;
   if(interval == 0)
   {
      $(element).val("Move on to next date...");
      var interval = 3*60;
   }
   else
   {
      $(element).html(interval + " seconds left");
   }
}
```